# Failed to Print the Length of List for Each Line Read?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After reading text file and loop through each line, I tried to output the 2nd item from a list, which is a list as well as below.

```
with open('xxx.txt','r') as f:
   for l in f.readlines():
      s=l.split("\t")
      s[1]=s[1].replace('/','')
      s[1]=s[1].replace('\n','')
      s[1]=s[1].split(',')
      print(s[1]))
```

Below is the result after running code above in ipython notebook.

[image: list_printing]

However, I got the error saying the **int** is not callable when I tried to 
`print(len(s[1]))`. 
I'm not sure what went wrong.

[image: list_length]

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I already posted the code.

Comment: The comment is poorly worded. **Don't** upload images of code.

Comment: Your edits have made your question even worse by adding code to it that doesn't match what's in the image. Besides that, neither of them could generate the `int is not iterable` error you say you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
print(len(s))
```

because `print(len(s[1]))` means length of second element of the list.

Comment: In my case, the second item happens to be a list. I'm trying to figure out the length of the second item for each line read from text file.

Comment: @moiaussi06 Maybe the second item is a integer in the text file

Comment: No, all items within the second item are strings.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me the line where this error occurs

Comment: try this print(len(list(s[1])))

Comment: @moiaussi06 try this print(len(list(s[1])))

Comment: I tried to print the type(s[1]) and it says it's a list. I also tried your method but **print(len(list(s[1])))** but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @moiaussi06 how can you split a list in s[1].split(',')

Comment: It was a large chunk of string that goes "/page1,/page2"